# AngularJS with Sharepoint 2010 not working

Tags: 2010, angularjs

- we're testing our custom webparts using angular.js
- in Sharepoin 2013 it works but not within our SP 2010 Environment
- the needed angular and jquery library are linked correctly

As test code in the webpart we just use

```
<script src="../../_layouts/Angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../../_layouts/Angular/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="search">
     <p>you're searching for: {{search}}</p>
</div>
```

We as well tried to Change the browser compatibiliy advised in
http://niftit.com/angularjs-in-sharepoint-2010/
but showing the page with the webpart angular is not bound (showing "{{search}}" - in any browser.

What could be the reason that the active script is not executing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same experience when migrated our SP2013-based AngularJS solutions to SP2010. The problem was in our case a kind of timing issue.

The solution was to introduce a 1-2 seconds of delay in the controller before calling the methods of our SharePoint service:

```
setTimeout(function () { 
    $scope.getContacts($scope, mySharePointService); 
}, 1000);
```

Further steps that may help:
Instead of `<div ng-app="myApp">` use `<div ng-app="myApp" id="ng-app">`

Disable the `$sce` service of AngularJS in the application if the document is displayed in quirks mode. We can achieve that via the config method of the application:

```
myApp.config(function ($sceProvider) { 
    // Completely disable SCE to support IE7 (quirks mode in SharePoint 2007 / 2010). 
    // SCRIPT5022: [$sce:iequirks] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.6/$sce/iequirks 
    if ((document.documentMode == 5) || (document.documentMode == 7)) { 
        // or: if (document.documentMode < 8) { 
        $sceProvider.enabled(false); 
    } 
});
```

See details [here](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2015/02/11/migrating-angularjs-based-sharepoint-2013-applications-to-former-sharepoint-versions/).

Comment: Hi All, what are the steps to implement Angular 2 in the SharePoint 2010?