# angularjs with Sharepoint 2013 using ajax

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, angularjs

Although it discussed here:
[AngularJS with Sharepoint 2010 not working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/143644/angularjs-with-sharepoint-2010-not-working)
And uses of timeout in order to make the page being loaded synchronous (I don't like this solution) - it's not work.

I have loaded the html of the webpart page after the angular is loaded:

```
window.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){       
        str+='<p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter 
        name here"></p>'        
        str+='<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>'                
        str+='<button id="submit"></button>'

        document.getElementById("ngApp").innerHTML=str;    
    }, 2500);
}
```

The output is: "Hello {{name}}"

```
    <script src=".../angularjs.js"></script>
<script src=".../code.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Eyal, are you using a server-side webpart to add HTML to the page?

Comment: Hi Denis - not, everything in the Front

Answer (score 2):

When Loading Content or Libraries Async, you have to initialize AngularJS manually, after all your content and libraries are loaded. This is called manual initialization (or sometimes manual bootstrapping):

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
```

Refer to the [Angular Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manual-initialization) for a detailed description.

Comment: Thank you! whre shoul I put the bootstrapping?